# Using substrings to get integers and a character from a string in Java?

Tags: java, substring

> The user is asked to enter a temperature, then the user enters a number followed by either C or F for Celsius or Fahrenheit. The program is then to recognise the temp and what unit the temp is being measured in - using this data it tells your whether the "water" is solid, liquid or gaseous.

I've tried the below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter THE temp: ");
    String ent = myScan.next();


    int temp = Integer.parseInt(ent.substring(0,4));

    //char type = ent.charAt();
    //System.out.println(temp);
    // System.out.println(type);

    if (temp >= 100) {
        System.out.println("The water is gaseous");
    } else if (temp < 0) {
        System.out.println("The water is solid");
    } else {
        System.out.println("the water is liquid");
    }

}
```

When I put the (0,4) in the temp substring, I would've thought that the output would be the first 3 numbers that are entered. Instead I get an error "java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException" when I enter 1 int or 3.

Comment: When getting a line from user input (through `System.in`), it's best to use `Scanner#nextLine()`, as that gets the whole line, rather than the first token.

Comment: What is your test data btw @Kieron?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it is searching for a character that is out of bounds of the string.
Instead of hard coding the string length to 4 use ent.length().

```
int temp = Integer.parseInt(ent.substring(0,ent.length()-1));
```

You may also need a formula to convert to Celsius if the last character is F

```
substring(ent.length()-1).equalsIgnoreCase("F");
```

Comment: `substring(ent.length()-1)` would be easier.

Comment: @tom this is for another program now, my actual course work.. "int timeCru = Integer.parseInt(cruSpec.substring(5,6));" why doesnt this work if my input is BIDC 0 HSBCK? I'm getting an out of bounds error, totally going over my head this.

Comment: Is the Scanner still pulling next? > myScan.next();? It may be passing BIDC only... you should change to myScan.nextLine();

Comment: All sorted, dude. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

First, ask for Celsius or Fahrenheit and then ask for units to the user. 
http://prntscr.com/phx15j

asking to enter temperature like this--> 50C is wrong.

Comment: _asking to enter temperature like this--> 50C is wrong_; it's not "wrong,"  just more work to program than some of the alternatives.

Comment: by manipulating the input of the user you can perform the above operation but if a user enters invalid data, or how you going to validate the input field or how different types of validations you are going to put so its better to separate the fields. Its not an alternatives it's a solution according to me.

Comment: @AdalSkhan, We can alter the validations for the both inputs 50C and [C, 50] but I think, we can reduce the number actions of the users by the input style 50C. so we can go with the input style 50C and adapt our code to support this input.

Comment: Yeah, it may be easier to ask for one then the other. But the "challenge" I've been given, and am currently stuck with is having it all in one input.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the substring function, it takes all characters from beginIndex to endIndex - 1, so here, if you enter "123something", the result will be "123s", as char of index 3 is 's'.

On the other hand, if you only enter "12c", the substring will throw an error, as there is no char at index 3.

Personally, I would've gone for a regex here, as the temperature may be in 1, 2 or 5 chars, depending on how you write it.

Answer (score -1):

`s.substring(begin, end)` will return a string with characters from `begin` to `end - 1`.

If you want to extract all but last character, you can use

`s.substring(0, s.length() - 1)`

and for only the last character you can use

`s.substring(s.length() - 1, s.length())`.

You are getting `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` since the length of entered string is lesser than `end` (1 < 4 and 3  < 4 in you case).

Comment: `substring` is overloaded where `substring(s.length() - 1)` is the same as `s.substring(s.length() - 1, s.length())`